# How to display JSON data readable way for users in laravel?

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel, foreach

In my controller i have like this

```
public function show(Document $document){
$doc = DB::table('adjustments')->where('document_id', $document->id)->get();
return view('documents.show',compact('document','doc'));
    }
```

In my view i have like this

```
@foreach($doc as $user)
<pre>{{ $user->before}}</pre>
 <pre>{{ $user->after}}</pre>
@endforeach
```

Im getting output like this

```
{"title":"Nam beatae tempora nulla magnam accusantium neque eligendi magni.","body":"Unde doloremque omnis aspernatur atque illo quaerat. Esse nulla iure porro error est laborum. Debitis saepe pariatur voluptatem nulla non quam excepturi corporis."}
{"title":"new title","body":"new body"}
```

but i want show like this 
Title :.......... Body :.........
Title :.......... Body :.........

UPDATED
when i try dd($doc);

```
 array:3 [▼
      0 => {#194 ▼
        +"id": 1
        +"user_id": 1
        +"document_id": 1
        +"before": "{"title":"Nam beatae tempora nulla magnam accusantium neque eligendi magni.","body":"Unde doloremque omnis aspernatur atque illo quaerat. Esse nulla iure porro error est laborum. Debitis saepe pariatur voluptatem nulla non quam excepturi corporis."}"
        +"after": "{"title":"new title","body":"new body"}"
        +"created_at": "2016-05-09 07:16:29"
        +"updated_at": "2016-05-09 07:16:29"
      }
      1 => {#195 ▼
        +"id": 3
        +"user_id": 1
        +"document_id": 1
        +"before": "{"body":"new body"}"
        +"after": "{"body":"new body seccond body "}"
        +"created_at": "2016-05-09 14:31:53"
        +"updated_at": "2016-05-09 14:31:53"
      }
      2 => {#196 ▼
        +"id": 4
        +"user_id": 1
        +"document_id": 1
        +"before": "{"body":"new body seccond body "}"
        +"after": "{"body":"new body seccond body jerry "}"
        +"created_at": "2016-05-09 14:32:47"
        +"updated_at": "2016-05-09 14:32:47"
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Add a new dimension for getting access of `title` and `body`....
ex: `$user->before->title`.

Comment: No i tried `$user->before->title` i will get error **Trying to get property of non-object**

Comment: So did this: `$user->before['title']`..

Comment: this is also i tired **Illegal string offset 'title'**

Comment: Checkout my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this:

```
@foreach($doc as $user)
    <div>
        <strong>Before</strong>
        Title: {{ $user->before->title }}<br />
        Body: {{ $user->before->body }}
    </div>
    <div>
        <strong>After</strong>
        Title: {{ $user->after->title }}<br />
        Body: {{ $user->after->body }}
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: No when i try {{ $user->before->title }}  i will get error **Trying to get property of non-object**

Answer (score 0):

```
try this :
@foreach($doc as $user)
$before = json_decode($user->before);
$after = json_decode($user->after);
<pre>Title:{{ $before['title'] }}Body:{{ $before['body'] }}</pre>
<pre>Title:{{ $after['title'] }}Body:{{ $after['body'] }}</pre>
@endforeach
```

Comment: i tried before in this line $before = json_decode($user->before); error undefined variable because in laravel view $user->before their is no output :(

Answer (score -1):

You have a json in your code now, You need to decode the variable for access rest of the code.

> If your `$user->before` variable gives `{"title":"Nam beatae tempora
>   nulla magnam accusantium neque eligendi magni.","body":"Unde
>   doloremque omnis aspernatur atque illo quaerat. Esse nulla iure porro
>   error est laborum. Debitis saepe pariatur voluptatem nulla non quam
>   excepturi corporis."}` then my script must work.

Working example: [**https://3v4l.org/liLnr**](https://3v4l.org/liLnr)

So try with it:

```
@foreach($doc as $user)
    $before = json_decode($user->before);
    $after = json_decode($user->after);
    <pre>Title:{{ $before->title}}Body:{{ $before->body}}</pre>
    <pre>Title:{{ $after->title}}Body:{{ $after->body}}</pre>
@endforeach
```

Comment: No i tired this way but im getting error **Trying to get property of non-object**

Comment: please give your full `$doc`.

Comment: yes i tried like this `$doc = DB::table('adjustments')->where('document_id', $document->id)->get();
        foreach($doc as $d){
            $data= $d->before;
            $d = json_decode($data,true);
            var_dump($d);
            //return view('documents.show',compact('document','d'));
        }` so im getting out put like this

Comment: `array(2) { ["title"]=> string(65) "Nam beatae tempora nulla magnam accusantium neque eligendi magni." ["body"]=> string(162) "Unde doloremque omnis aspernatur atque illo quaerat. Esse nulla iure porro error est laborum. Debitis saepe pariatur voluptatem nulla non quam excepturi corporis." } array(1) { ["body"]=> string(8) "new body" } array(1) { ["body"]=> string(22) "new body seccond body " }`

Comment: because of `true` in `json_decode($data,true)`, you got associative array, if you don't use it then you will gor array object.

Comment: in this line im getting error undefined variable `$before = json_decode($user->before);`

Comment: I can't understand what's going on! I am damn sure that my script will run fine and not have error, Check your top level variable properly. Try to copy entire `foreach loop`.

Comment: in a view we have used `$before = json_decode($user->before);` but in view  `($user->before)` not any out put right and i tried this also `$before = json_decode({{$user->before}});` but no use

Comment: Dude we  have to decode in our controller not a view will see i will try