# Laravel Eloquent get data from second level table

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have tables: `operations`, `remarks` and `adjustments`.

`operations`:

```
| id  | user_id  |  operation   |  start_date |  end_date   |
|  1  |     2    |  opeartion1  |    1/1/16   |   5/5/16    |
|  2  |     2    |  opeartion2  |    1/1/16   |   5/5/16    |
```

`remarks`:

```
|  id  |  user_id  |  operation_id  |    remarks    |
|  10  |     4     |       1        |  remarks1 new | 
|  13  |     4     |       2        |  remarks22new |
```

`adjustments`:

```
| id | remarks_id | user_id |         before         |             after            |      created_at     |      updated_at     |
|:--:|:----------:|:-------:|:----------------------:|:----------------------------:|:-------------------:|:-------------------:|
|  1 |     10     |    6    | {"remarks":"remarks1"} | | {"remarks":"remarks1 new"} | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
|  2 |     13     |    7    | {"remarks":"remarks1"} | | {"remarks":"remarks1 new"} | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
```

I want get data from `adjustments` table for particular `operation_id` like this in `Operation` controller's `show()` method:

```
$history = Adjustment::with('user','remark')->get();
```

From this I'm getting all the rows from `adjustments` table like this:

```
Jerry Nienow 2016-05-12 07:00:24 {"remarks":"remarks1"} {"remarks":"remarks1 new"}
Jerry Nienow 2016-05-12 07:01:09 {"remarks":"remarks22"} {"remarks":"remarks22new"}
```

but I want a particular `operation_id` like this:

```
Jerry Nienow 2016-05-12 07:00:24 {"remarks":"remarks1"} {"remarks":"remarks1 new"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just join the `remarks` table and get the results with this `$operationId`:

```
Adjustment::join('remarks', 'remarks.id','=', 'adjusments.remarks_id')->where('remarks.operation_id', '=', $operationId)->get();
```

*You should set `$operationId` first.*

Comment: :) :) :) if you are expert in laravel please answer this questions also [Question 1](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-display-json-data-more-redable?page=1#reply-162307)

Comment: @Ivanko Todorova waiting for your answer :( [QQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37129211/how-to-display-json-data-readable-way-for-users-in-laravel)